# Deleting dynamically created rows - where do I need to put the delegate ()?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, delegates

I have inherited some code that isn't quite working ...

I have jsp which lays out a dialog box:

```
<div class="ShippingPoints">
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Shipping Points">
        <p class="validateTips">
            Please include all vendor ship points by product group. If vendor
            ships all products from one location input City, State, Zip Code
            then select "All" for product group.
        </p>

        <fieldset>
            <label font-family="Courier New" align="left" for="city">City</label>
            <input maxlength=50 align="right" type="text" name="city" id="city"
                class="text ui-corner-all" />
            <br />
            <label font-family="Courier New" align="left" for="state">State</label>
            <select maxlength=6 align="right" name="state" id="state"
                class="text ui-corner-all">
                <c:forEach items="${states}" var="state">
                    <option value="${state.fieldValue}">
                        ${state.fieldDescription}
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
            <br />
            <label font-family="Courier New" align="left" for="stateOther">State (Other):</label>
            <input maxlength=6 align="right" type="text" name="stateOther" id="stateOther" value=""
                class="text ui-corner-all" />
            <br />
            <label font-family="Courier New" align="left" for="zip">Zip</label>
            <input align="right" maxlength=10 align="right" type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value=""
                class="text ui-corner-all" />
            <br />
            <label font-family="Courier New" align="left" align="left" for="product">Product</label>
            <input align="right" maxlength=50 type="text" name="product" id="product" value=""
                class="text ui-corner-all" />
            <br />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

On the page I have a link which opens the dialog ... and a link that invokes the delete ...

```
<table id="shipPoints" class="ui-widget" width="697">
    <tr width="695">
    <td width="395"><a href="#" id="add-shipping-point"> Add Shipping Point </a></td>
    <td width="300">Click <img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/delete.gif"       onclick="deleteShippingPoints('shipPoints')" /> to remove checked shipping points</td>
</tr>           
</table>
```

That calls this jquery function

```
$j("#add-shipping-point").click(function() {
    $j("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Here is the full code for the dialog

```
$j(function() {
$j("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

var city = $j("#city"), state = $j("#state"), zip = $j("#zip"), product = $j("#product"), allFields = $j(
        []).add(city).add(state).add(zip).add(product), tips = $j(".validateTips");

function updateTips(t) {
    tips.text(t).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout( function() {
        tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    }, 500);
}

function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
    if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and "
                + max + ".");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkRequired(o, n) {
    if (o.val().length == 0) {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips(n + " is a required field.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
    if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips("Zip Code is not in proper format.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$j("#dialog-form")
    .dialog(
    {
    autoOpen : false,
    height : 500,
    width : 500,
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
            "Add Shipping Point" : function() {
            var bValid     = true;
            var cityValid  = true;
            var stateValid = true;
            var zipPresent = true;
            var zipValid   = true;

            updateTips("");
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            cityValid  = checkRequired(city, "City");
            stateValid = checkRequired(state, "State");
            zipPresent = checkRequired(zip, "Zip");
            if(zipPresent) { zipValid   = checkRegexp(zip, /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/, "Zip Code"); }

            bValid     = cityValid && stateValid && zipPresent && zipValid;

    if (bValid) {
        // make Ajax call save the Shipping Point and add to the list
        var shipPointId = saveShippingPoint();

        // alert(shipPointId);

        if (shipPointId == "na") {
            alert("There was a problem adding the Shipping Point.  Please try again.  
            If the problem persists please contact support.");
        } else {
            $j("#shipPoints tr:last").after(                                                                                        
                "<tr>"
                + "<td>"
                + city.val()
                + ", "
                + state.val()
                + "</td>"
                + "<td>"
                + "<INPUT type='checkbox' NAME='chk' VALUE='"
                + shipPointId
                + "' />"
                + "</td>"
                + "</tr>");
        }
        $j(this).dialog("close");
    }
},
Cancel : function() {
$j(this).dialog("close");
    }
},
close : function() {
    allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
}
});

$j("#add-shipping-point").click(function() {
    $j("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
});
```

The problem is that you can dynamically add rows to the table, and if you then check the checkbox and delete a newly created row it does
not delete. Essentially because the call to the delete shipping point passes in a blank id.

I've read around it I realize I have to use delegate to bind the event to the newly created roles. However the syntax of what I have doesn't seem 
quite match up with what's on the net, so I'm not sure where I would specify the delegate ?

Anybody have any ideas ?

Save and delete code is as follows

```
<script>
// Ajax call to add the Shipping Point to the Session
function saveShippingPoint() {

    var savedId = "";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            savedId = xhr.responseText;
            // alert(savedId);
        }
    };      
    var url = '<portlet:resourceURL id="saveShippingPoint"/>';
    xhr.open("GET", url + 
       "?city=" + $j( "#city" ).val() +
       "&state=" + $j( "#state" ).val() +
       "&stateOther=" + $j( "#stateOther" ).val() +
       "&zip=" + $j( "#zip" ).val() +
       "&product=" + $j( "#product" ).val()
       , true);
    xhr.send();

    // alert(savedId);
    return savedId;
}

// A function to delete rows from the Shipping Points table

function deleteShippingPoints(tableID) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var shippingPointsId = "";

for ( var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];

    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        shippingPointsId = shippingPointsId + chkbox.value + ",";
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}

var url = '<portlet:resourceURL id="deleteShippingPoint"/>';
xhr.open("GET", url + "?shippingPointsId=" + shippingPointsId, true);
xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code to do the row deletion? I assume that shipPointId is the id of the row you want to delete. Where is the code for the saveShippingPoint function? if it is an ajax call then it's possible it hasn't returned a value by the time the code outputs the checkbox.

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the code formatting issues. Also, some of your HTML is invalid (e.g. `<label font-family="Courier New" align="left" for="city">` -- there is no font-family attribute).

Comment: ok, added code for row deletion and saveShippingPoint ...  I will clean up the HTML, but I recently inherited the code, and I'm just trying to fix a defect associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the jquery to this

```
$j(function() {
$j("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

$j("#shipPoints2").delegate(".delete-shipping-points", "click", function () {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var table = document.getElementById('shipPoints');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var shippingPointsId = "";

for ( var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];

    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        shippingPointsId = shippingPointsId + chkbox.value + ",";
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}

var url = '<portlet:resourceURL id="deleteShippingPoint"/>';
xhr.open("GET", url + "?shippingPointsId=" + shippingPointsId, true);
xhr.send();
} );
```

(Rest is the same as before )

And JSP to this

```
<div id="shipping-points-contain">
<table id="shipPoints" class="ui-widget-content" width="697">
<thead>
<tr class="ui-widget-content"  width="696">
        <th class="ui-widget-header" width="395">
    Shipping Points
    </th>
        <th class="ui-widget-header" width="300">
    Remove
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${shippingPoints}" var="shippingPoint">
<tr width="695">
    <td with="395">
        ${shippingPoint.shippingPointsCity},
        ${shippingPoint.shippingPointsState}
    </td>
    <td width="300">
    <INPUT type="checkbox" NAME="chk" value="${shippingPoint.shippingPointsId}" />
    <INPUT type="hidden" NAME="shipPointId" VALUE="${shippingPoint.shippingPointsId}" />
    </td>                           
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="shipPoints2" class="ui-widget" width="697">
<tr width="695">
<td width="395"><a href="#" id="add-shipping-point"> Add Shipping Point </a></td>
<td width="300">Click <a href="#" id="delete-shipping-points"> <img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/delete.gif"  /></a>  remove checked shipping points</td>
</tr>           
</table>
</div>
```

And at least I'm not getting any syntax errors, the page displays properly and add still works, but the delete is not triggerred when I click the image, so the event binding isnt taking yet ......

Comment: in your delegation, change `.delete-shipping-points` to `#delete-shipping-points`

Comment: It is now triggering the event! But delete is still not working on the newly created rows ... so I'm back to where I started! lol, when I click the link its also kicking me back up to the top of the page ... I think this site needs link up with paypal so we can compensate people who are being helpful ! lol

Comment: haha no need to pay me. it's kicking you to the top of the page because your href is `#`. to disable this, at the beginning of your "delete" method, define `e` as your function parameter and then call `e.preventDefault()`. this will stop the link from doing what the href is telling it to do

Comment: as for your function not actually working, that's outside of the scope of this question. i'm just helping you get delegation working ;) if you really want to "compensate" me, vote my answer up and accept it :)

Comment: no no! The whole reason from switching from the way it was, to using delegate was to get the delete to work with the dynamically created elements ! So now I have new syntax, but the same behavior ! And I don't know how to vote for an answer, when I click on those arrows by the answer, it tells me I need a reputation of 15 ... and it doesn't seem right to accept an answer when the defect I'm trying to close is still open ! (:^)

Comment: the title of your question is 'where do I need to put the delegate ()?', which i feel has been sufficiently answered. Actually deleting the rows is another question.

Comment: True! However the question is really where do I need to put the delegate so that my dynamically created rows get deleted ... that's just a really long title, my initial description clearly states that as the problem ... still a problem ... my syntax is good, delete is using delegate, by dynamically created rows are still an issue...if I was to end this thread and accept the answer I would need to open another thread that asks the same question, where do I put the delegate to get it to delete the dynamically created rows ?

Comment: Accepted this answer, as you say, the delegate is working properly. I have tracked down the actual problem, which is the javascript that creates the newly created row is created BEFORE the ajax call which assigns the id returns with a value ... no id, unsuccessful delete. I'm going to post a separate question for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to `.delegate()` is that you must bind it to a container that already exists on the page. One way to guarantee this is to do `$(document).delegate('.myelement', 'click', myhandler);` which will make it function like `.live()`. However, if you want to get more performant, choose a container that is closer to the element you are going to bind to:

```
$('#mypermanentcontainer').delegate('.mydynamicthing', 'myevent', myhandler);
```

---

**update**

So looking at your code you have this line: `$j(function() { ... });`. I'm assuming you're using `$j` as an alias for `$` or `jQuery`. If so, `$j(function() {});` and `$j(document).ready(function(){});` are the exact same thing, which is code that will run when the DOM is ready (aka "document ready" in jQuery speak :). This is typically where event binding takes place. You already have some of this, your whole `$j("#dialog-form").dialog(...)` piece is event wiring that is happening within the `document.ready` function.

So, just drop all of the rest of your event wiring in there and you should be good to go!

Comment: But given my code above, where do I do the delegate ? That is what is escaping me ... I'm guessing it's the Add Shipping Point button that needs the binding, but It's unclear to me how to add it.

Comment: looking back at your code, put it under this line: `$j("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");`

Comment: lol, well I'm completely new to JQuery ... so I apologize for my ignorance ... but your //put event wiring here ... is also a mystery ... I know that I need to in some way bind Add Shipping Points to current and future rows of the table ... WIth all the code included all you fine folk know as much about the app as I, except I don't know JQuery very well yet ! (:^)

Comment: @JamesGawron i updated my answer for you. should be clearer i hope!

Comment: appreciate your help. Ok, so the trick is I'm trying to figure out what to bind ... So what's happening is that the user clicks an "Add Shipping Points" hyperlink which opens a dialogue...in the dialogue some information about the shipping point is entered and an "Add Shipping Point" button on the dialogue is pressed. This creates the new dynamic row. Then on the screen there is a checkbox on the row. If that is checked and a "Delete Shipping Point" hyperlink is pressed the row should be deleted, but is not ... so the question would be ... which element needs the delegate?

Comment: I'm thinking it would be the delete hyperlink ? As that is the one that needs to read the id off the checkbox and make the ajax call for deletion, so it needs to be bound to the new elements. If I'm saying that correctly. I'm going to add the delete link jsp to the original comment...

Comment: So If I'm right, I'm event binding the click of the delete hyperlink to the tr elements of the table ?

Comment: no, you should delegate the outermost element that always exists on the page, be it a table or div, and then select the link: `$('#mytable').delegate('.mylink', 'click', mycallbackfunction)`

Comment: Ok So I attempted to insert my binding, but now my div that was populating the popup box is displaying in the page itself, the delete button is broken ... and I get "Errors on page" in lower left that says that object does not support property or method ... lol ... bad first attempt ... Comment with code to follow .... I removed some of the middle of the method for the post just so it would fit ... I put the binding right after the dialogue destroy as instructed.

Comment: $("#shipPoints2").delegate(".delete-shipping-points", "click", function deleteShippingPoints(tableID) {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 

 
 for ( var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var chkbox = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];

  if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
   shippingPointsId = shippingPointsId + chkbox.value + ",";
   table.deleteRow(i);
   rowCount--;
   i--;
  }
 }
 
 var url = '<portlet:resourceURL id="deleteShippingPoint"/>';
 xhr.open("GET", url + "?shippingPointsId=" + shippingPointsId, true);
 xhr.send();
} );

Comment: Getting close Jason, added code in a new "Answer here, comment thread was getting long and I wanted to repost updated code ... must be doing something wrong with the event binding ....